# plunker always refers to github script link

Tags: angularjs, plunker

I can not execute this plunker because of this error message:

but I am not referencing accordion.js at all from github its locally !!!

What do I wrong that I get that message?

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled. run.plnkr.co/:1
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module plunker due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap.accordion due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap.accordion' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/WYkxKqUOZAhT07HyuTOh?p=preview

Comment: "Refused to execute script from 'https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Comment: but where do I run this github script?

Comment: `<script src="https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.js"></script>`

Comment: either I am blind... but I can not see this code in my plunker!

Comment: It's in the head section of your index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

First you have forgotten about to add the bootstrap js, jquery and ui-bootstrap-tpls script to the index.html
Second, you only need the ui.bootstrap dependency.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker',['ui.bootstrap']);
```

Finally, here's a working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Hntx2YihOb3U0HoGMQAQ?p=preview

Comment: instead of the bootstrap-tpls file I used the accordion.js thats total valid and jquery is not needed. but thanks for the working plunker.

Comment: you need bootstrap-tpls for the 'ui.bootstrap' dependency because you need the bootstrap accordion and since you use bootstrap you need the bootstrap.js which needs jquery ;)

Comment: I use angularjs ui bootstrap component which is written WITHOUT jquery have a look: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/